# Wolfram Neural Net Repository Questions

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-networks, text, sound

I was a research scientist in the machine learning team, and mostly involved with the neural net repository.

Comment: For "prettifying" do you mean structure the model construction to meaningful blocks as you do in the ConstructionNotebook? Can you give an example of "ugly" vs "pretty"?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2360563).

Comment: Yes, for example if you open an ONNX graph in a viewer, it appears to be kind of messy, however you can see them have a structure in WL. While re-structuring some blocks do not take much time, however, for more complicated graphics like you would see in object detection, this practically means reconstructing the entire network by hand.
For any practical purpose though, you can do surgeries the relevant parts, even without the "prettied" subparts.

Comment: I prefer a greater variety of "turn-key" deep nets, for a wider range of tasks.  I think most users play around with lots of networks before they move into developing their own.  I'd also like a cleaner interface for training with our own data sets.  Another annoyance:  OpenPose (to take one example) works with v. 12 but not 11.0.  Can you make these networks more back compatible?

Comment: This is the funniest Edit to a question.

Answer (score 11):

I believe I'm a heavy user of the neural network framework and the Wolfram Neural Network Repository(WNNR) and these are how I see the WNNR from a user's perspective. Hope it will be helpful.

First of all, I think the developers are doing a great job putting together the neural network framework and the WNNR. The framework is well designed and easy to use. The documentation is concise and informative. I found many times I refer to the documentation and WNNR to understand a deep learning concept or a network model.

In my opinion, WNNR is a great extension of the neural network framework. The framework itself is concise. But perhaps because of the computational limitation of the documentation within Mathematica, examples in the documentation are often too simple and considered as toy problems. When applying the framework to real-world problems, there is often a big gap from these toy examples. And I think that's where WNNR comes in place. WNNR basically closes that gap to some extent, as most of the WNNR models are from publications that try to solve real-world problems. I personally use the `ConstructionNotebook` option very often to get more understanding of how a deep learning concept is implemented in real systems.

Let me give a concrete example using the `AttentionLayer`. In the documentation, the only example of `AttentionLayer` is about sorting 6 single-digit numbers. However, more practical usage of multi-head attention (for example in transformers) is not documented. With the help of the WNNR, I can just look up how it is constructed and even reuse part of the source code in the construction notebook for my own problem. Without a structured notebook, I will have to resort to the original paper and other python implementations for the details. With the structure and "pretty" of the models, WNNR takes much of the burden away from the users.

Moreover, I think reusability is more important than scope coverage. I found that it almost never happens that a WNNR model solves exactly the problem I have on hand. There are always some modifications I need to make to models. I would personally prefer a structured model that is easier to understand and modify.

In conclusion, I can imagine that using an automatic system to load the unstructured model to WNNR may require less manual effort, but I think a large portion of the values of the WNNR lies within the structures of a model because it bridges the gaps between the well-designed framework that are clean and concise and practical problems that sometimes are messy. The structure or "pretty" of a model not only extends the documentation of best practices approach with real-world problems but also provides reusable structures in terms of code and distilled knowledge.

Comment: The ability to re-train networks is the most critical thing. Construction notebooks training details are often empty. Nobody wants to just run models, they want to fine tune them! And usually that is totally non-obvious here.

Comment: I agree, the ability to re-train the networks would be the ultimate piece to close the loop. I suspect most of the converted networks are not tested with training abilities and their weights are simply from the published trained networks from other systems. I think the best is that for every model WNNR can reproduce the model construction, model training, and model evaluation all within the Wolfram system rather than just loading the weights trained in other places. However, I can see that it would involve a lot of work to get the training work for most of the models.

Comment: Many of the models, except for the transformers (where fine-tuning is only possible with a lot of computational resources, multiple GPU-s, so we have a classifier training with it), and object detection models (which we are working to add sections for fine tuning), have fine tuning section. Trained feature extractors can have multiple uses, and some of them (the relevant ones) are shown with the model.

Comment: Again, there are differences between retraining and fine-tuning. Re-training requires a lot of computation resources for each model which are mostly unavailable to us (or our day-to-day users). The primary use of having a library of trained net models is to provide users the pre-trained and correct weights, so that they don't have to train the model from scratch and just fine-tune them (for their application areas), there's section for network surgeries in relevant models to get Feature Extractors and do classifications, similarly for the Feature Extraction Tasks.

Comment: I agree that most of the models are probably too large to train from scratch and there is probably no need for that for most users. I think ultimately, it is about reusability, i.e. whether it's easy to adapt the model to a specific problem/dataset. A fine-tune section would definitely be very helpful. I can see that there is a lot of work involved in importing a network to WNNR and I think the developer is currently doing a good job.

Comment: My motivation of writing this answer is that I was concerned that those "prettify" efforts will go away and a future converted model would be a spaghetti graph presented using the low-level MXNet operators (like what you get by importing the onnx model), which would be much less useful for the users. I'm also wondering whether wolfram is considering the possibilities of open WNNR for user contributions, just like wolfram function repository, which may greatly accelerate the growth of the WNNR.

Comment: For your concern about not prettifying - we will absolutely not just import the ONNX models and leave it as the low-level graph that you would see. The fact that we go over the architecture, and restructure them according to the original paper and/or sections that can be easily performed surgery on. I agree having a ONNX Import dump would not be aesthetically pleasing and/or user friendly. So your concern is well received. However, prettifying to the lowest level possible takes a lot of effort, so the question was if a middle ground is still acceptable. Maybe in the process I can share details

Comment: Thank you, I will convey your message to the team members concerned. Also, yes, we are aiming towards having a fine tune section for most of the available models in foreseeable future. We might not be able to provide it for all the models (but we will try our best for majority of them).